# Flask - boolean form

Tags: forms, flask, boolean

i'm running locally a python file. when i access 127.0.01:5000/string i get to a specific html page. Up to now, using javascript, i managed to put some checkbox (boolean form) on that page, but how can i assign the value of each one of them (True or False) to a variable in the python file?

i'm being unable to use the user's response in anyway.

i'm using flask-ext-wtforms, render_template, etc.

this is what i have on the html file so far.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
var creature=0
var artifact=0
function suggest(){

if ($('#Creature').is(':checked')){creature=1;}  

if ($('#Artifact').is(':checked')){artifact=1;} 
}
</script>

<input type="checkbox" id = "Creature">Creature<br>
<input type="checkbox" id = "Artifact">Artifact<br>
<input type="checkbox" id = "Enchantment"> Enchantment<br>
<input type="checkbox" id = "Sorcery"> Sorcery<br>

<button type="button" onclick = "suggest(); alert('creature ' + creature + ' artifact ' + artifact)">Submit</button>
```

It tells me whether or not the user has clicked one of the first two boxes, but that's it. i don't know how to make the python file access such information.

Comment: You will need to post data back to your flask application (either via javascript or by submitting a form) that will then allow you to access that data from within Flask. Check out the flask-wtforms examples.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be useful to see what you have in the actual Python file, but I'll give it a go. Also I'll state right off the bat that for these sorts of questions the documentation should be your best friend and first go-to, but here's a start.

From the html you've posted it doesn't look like you're actually using a Flask-WTF Form instance. You would want to first create a `Form` with `BooleanField`s like so:

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms import BooleanField

class MyForm(Form):
    creature = BooleanField()
    # etc
    submit = SubmitField()
```

then in your template render the form & the fields like so:

```
<form method="POST" action="/string">
  {{ form.creature.label }}
  {{ form.creature() }}
  {# ... etc ... #}
  {{ form.submit() }}
</form>
```

Then finally in your view, you have to (A) specify that the view accepts POST requests, (B) create the form, and (C) make sure you pass the form to the template for rendering. If you do all these things, then when you, or someone else, or a robot or whatever click submit, then the browser will POST the data from the form to the flask view, and you will be able to access it in the view as, say, form.creature.data. Example:

```
@route('/string', methods=['GET', 'POST']) # part A
def get_critters():
    form = MyForm() # part B
    if form.validate_on_submit(): 
        # do something with form.creature, or form.whatever
    return render_template("string.html", form=form) # part C
```

All of this is very ably covered in multiple parts of each project's documentation. See:

https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html
https://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#wtforms.fields.BooleanField

and virtually everything at http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/ but especially http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/wtforms/ and http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/tutorial/.